# Ошибка: AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute 'info'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Помогите, не знаю как исправить ошибку :

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


class Rabochiy(Test):
    def __init__(self, name, age, salary, country, past):
        Test.__init__(self, name, age)

        self.past = past
        self.country = country
        self.salary = salary
        print('it\'s {}, he is {} years old\nHis salary is {} uah'.format(name, age, self.salary))

    def info(self):
        Test.info(self)
        print('{} has leaved in {} and at {} yars old he has worked as a {}'.format(self.name, self.age, self.past))

r = Rabochiy('Nikolai', 37, 4000, 'San Francisco', 'courier')
l = [r]
for i in l:
    i.info()
```

Comment: `Test.info(self)` у вас в Test нет метода info.

Answer (score 1):

Держи, сравни коды

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


class Rabochiy(Test):
    def __init__(self, name, age, salary, country, past):
        Test.__init__(self, name, age)

        self.past = past
        self.country = country
        self.salary = salary
        print('it\'s {}, he is {} years old\nHis salary is {} uah'.format(name, age, self.salary))

    def info(self):
        print('{} has leaved in {} and at {} yars old he has worked as a {}'.format(self.name, self.country, self.age, self.past))

r = Rabochiy('Nikolai', 37, 4000, 'San Francisco', 'courier')
l = [r]
for i in l:
    i.info()
```

Я убрал строчку Test.info(self) и добавил аргумент в строчку ниже(ты скобок{} поставил 4,а аргументов дал 3))